# rails how to make a Conditional CLASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%=f.text_area :content, :class => 'grow'
```

I want the class to be conditional to be either "grow" or "nogrow"

I tried

```
<%=f.text_area :content, :class => grow ? "comment_content grow" : "nogrow"
```

but that errors. any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to add, grow is either TRUE OR FALSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:class => grow ? "comment_content grow" : "nogrow"` works just fine for me, you just need to end the line with `%>`. I suppose you could add some brackets - `:class => (grow ? "comment_content grow" : "nogrow")`, better for readability anyway.

Answer (score 6):

It's all about String Interpolation. Try This...

```
<%=f.text_area :content, :class => "#{grow ? 'comment_content grow' : 'nogrow'}" %>
```

Comment: I like this one a bit more for multiple classes. String interpolation is the only thing I could see working, unless you want to push that logic out to a helper.